# webgl drawElements:attribs not setup correctly (repeated n times)

Tags: arrays, webgl

So, I've begun a rather instantaneous trip into the world of visual, 3-d programming. I'm currently heavily invested in webgl with a rather strong background in JavaScript and most web-oriented languages but this is my first graphics language.

While trying to draw my first rather simple shape, I've run into an error I can't seem to locate a solution for. It reads in chrome as a:

WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawElements:attribs not setup correctly (repeated n times)

where n is a number that varies seemingly randomly. The code in question is here:

```
var tessVertexPositionBuffer;
var tessVertexColorBuffer;
var tessVertexIndexBuffer;
function initBuffers () {
    tessVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tessVertexPositionBuffer);
    var vertices = [
    //innerfront
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    //innerleft
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    //innerback
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    //innerright
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                                            
    //topfront
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        -2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
        2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
    //topleft
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        -2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        -2.0, 2.0, -2.0,
    //topback
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        -2.0, 2.0, -2.0,
        2.0, 2.0, -2.0,         
    //topright
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        2.0, 2.0, -2.0,
        
                                
    //outerfront
        -2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
        2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
        -2.0, -2.0, 2.0,
        2.0, -2.0, 2.0,
    //outerleft
        -2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
        -2.0, -2.0, 2.0,
        -2.0, 2.0, -2.0,
        -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,           
    //outerback
        -2.0, 2.0, -2.0,
        2.0, 2.0, -2.0,
        -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
        2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
    //outerright
        2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
        2.0, -2.0, 2.0,
        2.0, 2.0, -2.0,
        2.0, -2.0, -2.0,            
            
    //bottomfront       
        2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
        -2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
        -2.0, -2.0, 2.0,
        2.0, -2.0, 2.0,
    //bottomleft
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        -2.0, -2.0, 2.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
    //bottomback
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
        2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
    //bottomright
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        2.0, -2.0, 2.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        2.0, -2.0, -2.0
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    tessVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    tessVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 64;
    
    tessVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tessVertexColorBuffer);
    var colors = [
        [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0], //all inner sides
        [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0], 
        [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0], 
        [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0], 
        
        [0.7, 0.0, 0.7, 1.0], //all top sides
        [0.7, 0.0, 0.7, 1.0], 
        [0.7, 0.0, 0.7, 1.0], 
        [0.7, 0.0, 0.7, 1.0], 
        
        [0.7, 0.7, 0.0, 1.0], //all outer sides
        [0.7, 0.7, 0.0, 1.0], 
        [0.7, 0.7, 0.0, 1.0], 
        [0.7, 0.7, 0.0, 1.0], 
        
        [0.0, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0], //all bottom sides
        [0.0, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0],
        [0.0, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0],
        [0.0, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0],
    ];
    var unpackedColors = [];
    for (var i in colors) {
        var color = colors[i];
        for (var j=0; j< 4; j++) {
            unpackedColors = unpackedColors.concat(color);
        }   
    }
    
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(unpackedColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    tessVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
    tessVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 64;


    tessVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, tessVertexIndexBuffer);
    var tessVertexIndices = [
        0, 1, 2,  0, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 6,  5, 6, 7,
        8, 9, 10,  9, 10, 11,
        12, 13, 14,  13, 14, 15,
        16, 17, 18,  17, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 22,  21, 22, 23,
        24, 25, 26,  25, 26, 27,
        28, 29, 30,  29, 30, 31,
        32, 33, 34,  33, 34, 35,
        36, 37, 38,  37, 38, 39,
        40, 41, 42,  41, 42, 43,
        44, 45, 46,  45, 46, 47,
        48, 49, 50,  48, 50, 51,
        52, 53, 54,  53, 54, 55,
        56, 57, 58,  57, 58, 59,
        60, 61, 62,  61, 62, 63
    ];  
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(tessVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    tessVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
    tessVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = 96;
}
```

and the actual drawing of the buffers is here:

```
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tessVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vetexPositionAttribute, tessVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tessVertexColorBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, tessVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, tessVertexIndexBuffer);
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, tessVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Now, this is relatively verbatim from learningwebgl, I'm really just trying to draw a simple shape. I'm relatively certain that my problem lies in my buffer types because I honestly don't uderstand much about them (and most literature on webGl I've found is either novice with a general understanding of the language or of the HYPERSUPERPRO variety).

I've checked over the actual vertex positions/colors/indices multiple times and unless I've just become familiar with the code enough that I'm blind to the simple errors, I can't find an error there.

Comment: Just an fyi, adding properties to WebGL objects is an anti-pattern. If you ever decide to handle context lost events you'll find that when the context is lost gl.createBuffer will return null and the lines that add properties will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your problem is just a small typo. The second line of your "actual drawing of buffers" code should be he following:

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, tessVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

You were missing the first `r` in `vertexPositionAttribute` on that line.

I modified the lesson 4 LearningWebGL tutorial to use your code (with the fixed typo) and I have a link to it [here](http://antonpantev.com/so-related/attribsnotsetup/custom_lesson4.html).

If you notice there is a blue triangle and a yellow triangle being drawn at the exact same position in space which causes some flickering. I'm not sure if that was intentional.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I appreciate it. Searched for that for hours. And that was definitely not intentional, so thanks again for pointing it out.

Comment: No problem, I know how it can be.